# Python ruamel.yaml - preserving single quote in value while dumping yaml

Tags: python, python-3.x, yaml

I am trying to dump the dictionary into yaml and facing the following issue.

```
connection = dict()
connection['authentication']= 'Username Password'
connection['dbname']= '{{client}}_DB'

ruamel.yaml.round_trip_dump(connection, sys.stdout)
```

What i got :

```
  connection:
    authentication: Username Password
    dbname: '{{client}}_DB'
```

We can see that single quote are removed from authentication but not from dbname.

What i expected:

```
  connection:
    authentication: 'Username Password'
    dbname: '{{client}}_DB'
```

Complete example from terminal

```
>>> import sys
>>> import ruamel.yaml
>>> connection = dict()
>>> connection['authentication']= 'Username Password'
>>> connection['dbname']= '{{client}}_DB'
>>> ruamel.yaml.round_trip_dump(connection, sys.stdout)
authentication: Username Password
dbname: '{{client}}_DB'
>>> print(connection)
{'authentication': 'Username Password', 'dbname': '{{client}}_DB'}
>>>
```

yaml is printed without single quote. My requirement is to have single quote around the value

Answer (score 0):

Quotes here just mean you input string. If you want add single quotes to 'Username Password' just use double quotes:

```
connection['authentication'] = "'Username Password'"
```

Comment: I did try it and it didn't work .. 
I get the following output 
```  
connection:
authentication: "'Username Password'"

```